# Replace <br /> from DB with DIVs on PHP

Tags: php, mysql, css

I have a text that comes from my db (mysql). This text is saved via  and in order to preserve the line breaking that the user has typed, I use the `nl2br` function.

The thing is that I want to make each paragraph a DIV so I'll be able to maintain a CSS class for hovering (like you have here: http://opendyslexic.org/try-it/).

I've tried this method:

```
$text = preg_replace('#<br \/>{1}(.*?)<br \/>{1}#', '<div class = "paragraph_edit">$1</div>', $text);
```

But it doesn't seems to work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: My Guess is that your `<br />` tags start a new line in your string. Normally the `.` does not match newlines. If you want the dot to match newlines too, you will have to add the `s` flag to your regex in order for this to work.

EDIT: Also the `{1}` your using only applies to the preceding character (a `<` in this case). If you want it to match the entire `<br />`, you should use a non-capturing group, like so `(?:<br \>){1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you using `nl2br` prior to storing in the database at all if you need to save line endings? The data already has the line endings in there, and your database can store them just fine, so this seems a very odd thing to do. Simply store with all those `\n` on there, and fetch from DB with those `\n` in there, then explode on `\n` and rejoin on "whatever you need" -- could be `implode("<br>",data)`, could be `"<div>" . implode("</div><div>",data) . "</div>"`, or anything else you need.

Also, on a modern HTML note: the HTML5 syntax for `<br>` is just that. Void elements are not self closing, so it looks like that `nl2br` package is generating bad HTML (or XHTML, which doesn't make a lot of sense to use in a modern browser world)

Comment: `nl2br` will generate HTML tags instead of XHTML if you pass `false` to the second parameter. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)

Comment: I'm not storing my data with nl2br. This comes after I pull the text.

Comment: no need for `nl2br` then. Just use `$shaped = "<div>" . implode("</div><div>", explore("\n", $fromdb)) . "</div>";`, done. Bonus points for giving those divs classes so they can be properly styled and querySelector'd

Comment: Thanks Mike! I used the explode `($text = explode("<br>", $text);)` and then the implode `$text = '<div class = "paragraph">' . implode('</div><div class = "paragraph">', $text) . '</div>';`. It works just fine :)